# regex not preceeded by a word

Tags: regex, string

I need to find all the strings in a set of c# files, unless they are inside a Contract.Require statement. There could be any amount of text in the string, so between the " and ", and any amount of text between the string and the Contract.Require.

I have this:

```
/".+"/
```

which finds strings, but I need to refine my search.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What happens if there are two strings on the same line? What if there is an escaped " inside a string?

Comment: not a regular grammar, can't work reliably

Comment: What if there is a commented-out string?

Comment: Most regular expressions implementations are no longer 'regular' : P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions, you can use negative lookbehind to ensure that your string is not preceded by `Contract.Require`. However, there are many caveats in this solution (such as commen, et cetera), so it's probably not your best option. Anyway, here's a simple **demonstration** (you need to **adapt** it) of using something similar in Python:

```
import re
reg = re.compile('(?<!Contract\.Require\()"([^"\\\]|\\\.)*"')
tests = [ 'Contract.Require("test string")',
          'OtherRequire("test string" + someVar)', 
          'String var = "testString";',
          'String another = "test\\"quotestring"',
          'String empty = ""' ]

for test in tests:
    m = reg.search(test)
    print test, "wasn't matched." if m == None else "matched " + m.group(0) + "."
```

**Output**:

```
Contract.Require("test string") wasn't matched.
OtherRequire("test string" + someVar) matched "test string".
String var = "testString" matched "testString".
String another = "test\"quotestring" matched "test\"quotestring".
String empty = "" matched "".
```

The lookbehind in the expression above is **`(?<!Contract\.Require\()`**, and the regex to match string literals is **`"([^"\\\]|\\\.)*"`**. This slightly more complicated regex for string literals is required in order to be able to match strings such as "quote\"quote".

Hope it helps.